# select multipat dosnt work direction in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, aspxcombobox

I use this code

```
<style>
Select{
text-align : right;
direction : right;
}
</style>
<Select  size="5" >
<option>سلام....</option>
...
..
</Select>
```

in all browser all the element assign as right except chrome , in chrome element assign as left

even I wrote

```
<Select dir ="rtl" >
```

but not work

after that I use this

```
<option dir ="rtl">سلام....</option>
```

but not work again

this is image of my result

(http://chromefalt.somee.com/result.html)
(http://jsfiddle.net/korooshbaghbani/3Jgs5)

I want chrome like another browser start at right

what am I doing ??

Comment: Can you make a small jsfiddle or jsBin

Comment: set width for select option.. width:200px;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/korooshbaghbani/3Jgs5/

its not work on chrome

Answer (score 2):

try this

CSS :

```
    <style>
        .dropdown {
            direction: rtl;
        }

        select{
            width:125px;
            float:left;
        }
   </style>
```

HTML :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <select id="sex" name="sex">
        <option value="0">اختر</option>
        <option value="1">ذكر</option>
        <option value="2">أثنى</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pragneshok/m5pgp/2/

Comment: thanks , its work but I want set size in select , when set size it's not work , but thanks again